# Right Arrow in Kadwa (Google Font) is too wide

Tags: css, webfonts, typography, google-fonts

In InDesign I use the Google Font Kadwa to generate a right arrow (→).

I load the font into my website but the arrow is too wide.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kadwa');

body {
  font-family: 'Kadwa';
}
```

```html
You see, the font is applied but the arrow is too wide →
```

On the Google Font page the arrow is rendered correctly. 
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kadwa?selection.family=Kadwa

I dont get it, what I am doing wrong. 
Would be nice if somebody has a solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that character is not being loaded with the font for some reason. You can actually force Google fonts to load a particular character or set of characters by including a *text* parameter in the request. (The characters must be [url encoded](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).)

I've added an additional font request below that loads a font with only the arrow character. This supplements the Kadwa font that's already been loaded, and everything shows up correctly.

I've also converted the arrow character to an HTML entity (`&rarr;`).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kadwa');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kadwa&text=%E2%86%92');

body {
  font-family: "Kadwa";
}
```

```html
This should have the correct arrow &rarr;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! I add the [link to the google fonts documentation on this toppic](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#optimizing_your_font_requests).